# Tefillin Shin Minhagim

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilin

There are different minhagim as to how the shin is supposed to look on the tefillin shel rosh. Is there somewhere where I can view each of the most common minhagim? (Ashkenaz, Sepharad, Arizal, Chabad, Teiman, etc.) Maybe someone could provide pictures of each?

Comment: Do you mean as opposed to how they look in the writing?

Comment: See R Dr Arusi's article about this in Masorah Leyosef 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want are simply pictures, I can present examples.

The first figure shows Beit Yosef, Ariza"l, and Sephardi shins for tefillin and the second, Chabad tefillin (and shin).

[image: Fig. 1 tefillin shins B"Y, Ar"i, Wellisch] 
[source](https://www.en.tefillin.co.il/touring-the-factory/forming-the-shin)

[image: Fig. 2 Chabad tefillin shin]

As far as I've seen, most Teimanim use the same shin as is found on Sephardi tefillin.